# CSV column is a nested JSON array

Tags: python, json, csv, nested

Need some help "unpacking" an irregular nested JSON array in a CSV column.

I want to flatten this column and append it to the rest of the dataset as a normal flat table.

1. When I load the pandas dataframe, the column has a bunch of \n's in it:[read_csv df output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmbIj.png)
2. Using the read_json, I still get these \n's [read json output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UDco.png)
3. When trying read_json on the regular dataframe
   df = pd.read_json(df_data, lines=True). I get a ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)

Schema: ['time','event_type','user_id','nested_data']

nested_data column from CSV:

```
{
  "message": {
    "event": {
      "clientSessionId": "c6411c02-f361-4f0e-893f-d180e9b74a5d",
      "details": {
        "network": {
          "effectiveType": "4g"
        }
```

Some other things I've tried:

flat = flatten_json(df_data.to_dict())
pd.json_normalize(flat) --> Turns the column into a single row

json.dumps(df['DATA']) --> TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable

df_data_normal = pd.json_normalize(df_data.to_json) -->TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

I even [followed the instructions here](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10#.y46j8vr6ghttps://medium.com/@amirziai/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10#.y46j8vr6g) but no luck:

Comment: Welcome to SO Coder_bob! Can you please share the code to show us what you tried and what did not work?

Comment: df_data_normal = pd.json_normalize(df_data.to_json) -->TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable.

Comment: json.dumps(df['DATA']) --> TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable

Comment: flat = flatten_json(df_data.to_dict())
pd.json_normalize(flat) --> Turns the column into a single rrow

Comment: The error `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable` tells you that you passed in a "method", in this case `to_json`. You probably wanted to call it by adding brackets. e.g. `df_data.to_json()`

Comment: @de1 Thanks for your reply. When I use df_data_normal = pd.json_normalize(df_data.to_json()) I get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Hi @coder_bob I would advise to revise the question to provide a minimal but reproducible example. For that I would also cut down the JSON to the minimal and include it in the code as you will find in the examples of the Pandas documentation. For the minimal example data, mention exactly what the desired output looks like, and what you are getting instead (an exception for now). Imagine making it easy for someone who tries to help you, by allowing that person to just copy and paste your code.

Comment: @de1 Thanks for your suggestions. I edited the post. Hope that makes it more clear. I am trying to append my data set with the flattened column that is currently a nested json structure and am unable to unpack it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your data will look like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import json
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA': [
...     '''
...     {
...         "field1": "value 1",
...         "parent": {
...             "nested1": "nested value 1"
...         }
...     }
...     ''',
...     '''
...     {
...         "field1": "value 2",
...         "parent": {
...             "nested1": "nested value 2"
...         }
...     }
...     '''
... ]})
>>> df
                                                DATA
0  \n    {\n        "field1": "value 1",\n       ...
1  \n    {\n        "field1": "value 2",\n       ...
```

### Data types

Let's first look at the types we are working with:

```
>>> type(df['DATA'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

That shows that `df['DATA']` is a `pd.Series`. That is in general true for every column.

```
>>> type(df['DATA'][0])
<class 'str'>
```

The first value is indeed a raw string, not a parsed JSON object.

### Parsing JSON

There are a number of ways to parse JSON. The basic Python package is `json` which contains `load` (file etc) and `loads` (string) to parse JSON. Since we are working with a string we can use `loads`. The [Python json documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) contains a lot of examples.

```
>>> json.loads(df['DATA'][0])
{'field1': 'value 1', 'parent': {'nested1': 'nested value 1'}}
```

Since `loads` accepts a `str`, we can't pass in a `pd.Series` or a list. The above parses a single value.

You could for example use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to parse every string in the `DATA` column.

```
>>> df['DATA'].apply(json.loads)
0    {'field1': 'value 1', 'parent': {'nested1': 'n...
1    {'field1': 'value 2', 'parent': {'nested1': 'n...
Name: DATA, dtype: object
```

### json_normalize

Looking at the first parameter of the [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) method that you mentioned:

> Parameters
>
> data: dict or list of dicts
>
> Unserialized JSON objects.

That basically clarifies the types you can pass in. i.e. it is expecting a parsed JSON object (not a `str`).

We can try that for the first parse the first value (a `dict`):

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df['DATA'][0]))
    field1  parent.nested1
0  value 1  nested value 1
```

Or all of the parsed data values (a `list` of `dict`s):

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(df['DATA'].apply(json.loads))
    field1  parent.nested1
0  value 1  nested value 1
1  value 2  nested value 2
```

### flatten_json

You could also apply the the `flatten_json` method from the [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10) before calling `json_normalize`.

```
>>> def flatten_json(y):
...     out = {}
...     def flatten(x, name=''):
...         if type(x) is dict:
...             for a in x:
...                 flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
...         elif type(x) is list:
...             i = 0
...             for a in x:
...                 flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
...                 i += 1
...         else:
...             out[name[:-1]] = x
...     flatten(y)
...     return out
... 
>>> pd.json_normalize(df['DATA'].apply(json.loads).apply(flatten_json))
    field1  parent_nested1
0  value 1  nested value 1
1  value 2  nested value 2
```

In this case the output is the same, but it would be different for more complex objects. Since that `flatten_json` looks to expect a single object, we are also using `apply` again to get each value processed by it.

Note that `apply` isn't very efficient for large datasets.

And that I hope is what you were after.

Hopefully this also explains a bit how you can use the types and the expected values (according to the documentation), to find your way around.